# How to create SAS Enterprise Guide Project without using SAS EG?

Tags: sas, project, enterprise-guide

I want to create a SAS Enterprise Guide project without using SAS EG. Thank you in advance for you answers.

Tried creating a zip file with SAS programs and renaming the .zip extension to .egp, but it does not work.

Comment: I would think this would be very difficult.  Why do you want to do this?  What sort of content do you want to have in the .egp file?  If you're goal is to reverse-engineer a .egp file, I suppose you could start by using EG to make an .egp file like you are trying to create, unzip it, and see what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that there's some legal issue with reverse engineering it.

That being said - .egp does seem to be an archive.

For the most part,
it contains folders of generated names for each program in the .egp, as well as a folder with a generated name for the built in git repository. 
and probably most importantly a .xml file describing the project, It also contains any embedded code.

I don't have time to go through it, but if you have Enterprise Guide licensed and just don't have access to it, perhaps ask a colleague to send an example project.

Answer (score -2):

If instead of creating a *.zip file, you create a *.txt file.
Changing it's extension to *.sas will create a SAS program.

Comment: It would actually be .EGP as .SAS are the actual program or script one user would make.